# Как считать содержимоё файла в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, ini

Решил написать расширение для мазилы,чтобы отладить сайт с тестами.
Задумка такая: под каждым вопросом в тесте есть кнопка "Проверить" с событием onclick в котором содержится ссылка на файл .ini с ответом. Достать эту ссылку из html с помощью js не составило труда, но как применить её дальше пока непонятно. Рядом с файлом js скрипта находится находится копия дирриктории, содержащая .ini файлы с ответами,к которой идёт запрос по onclick.
У меня была задумка открывать и считывать нужный .ini файл, вытягивать из него верные ответы и подсвечивать правильные ответы в тесте, но вот как открыть и считать файл я так и не смог понять, в гугле множесто примеров где объект file получается через `<input>`, что мне не подходит. Можно ли вообще открыть файл и считать его содержимое через js в этой ситуации?

Comment: Java Script не работает с файловой системой, в целях безопасности.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Насколько я понял, в целях безопасности конфиденциальных персональных данных таким образом использовать локальную дирректорию не получится.